# Unable to display current owner

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-access, ownership

I recently tried to update Docker. It failed due to a permissions on a folder issue.
This is a 'bin' folder located at "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin".
I cannot open it, delete it, etc.
Advanced security settings-> Owner says Unable to display current owner.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxSv3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ8TD.png)
I tried to change that, with no luck.
I logged with the administrator CMD and tried : **icacls  /grant administrators:F**..........
Chkdisk too, but nothing helped.

Is this because Docker has some elevated access to the file system that an Administrator cant alter. Even then, i uninstalled Docker, and tried again; no Luck.

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: try some software like [iobit unlocker](http://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php) or [unlocker](https://unlocker.en.softonic.com/)

Comment: Worked like a charm.... Thanks a lot!